# Leaflet OnClick data not dynamically

Tags: javascript, onclick, leaflet

I have e problem when click marker on my map leaflet and modal show only last data, not dynamically.

```
//Array
        var koordinat = [
            {id: 1, nama: 'Unesa', lat: -7.313047, lang: 112.727151},
            {id: 2, nama: 'Coffe Warsalam', lat: -7.310355, lang: 112.732151},
            {id: 3, nama: 'Kejaksaan', lat: -7.313824, lang: 112.733235},
        ];

        //var sikat = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < koordinat.length; i++) {
            sikat = new L.Marker(new L.latLng(parseFloat([koordinat[i].lat]), parseFloat([koordinat[i].lang]))).addTo(mymap);
            sikat.bindPopup(koordinat[i].nama).openPopup();

            var namamu= koordinat[i].nama;


            sikat.on('click', function() {
                //$("#nama").html(koordinat[i].nama);
                $('#Modal').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                    var modal   = $(this)

                    //Reset Isi Form
                    $('#info').trigger("reset");

                    modal.find('#nama').attr("value",namamu);
                })
                //$("#Modal").modal("show");
            });
        }
```

I want data show on current marker clicked. Thanks guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much probably a classic JavaScript scope issue with `var` being hoisted whereas the developer does not expect it.

Replace `var` in `var namamu= koordinat[i].nama;`

By `const`: `const namamu= koordinat[i].nama;`

So that your `namamu` variable become bound to the inner `for` block scope.